# GraphFactory could not find gremlin.graph property configration

Tags: python-3.x, orientdb, gremlin, gremlin-server

**Summary**

While trying to start the gremlin server with origindb `GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not find [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientEmbeddedFactory]` error i got

**Detail**

I am using the below configuration

Gremlin : `apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.3.1`

Orientdb : `orientdb-tp3-3.0.2`

for download jar files use `bin/gremlin-server.sh -i com.orientechnologies orientdb-gremlin 3.0.2`

gremlinpython : 3.3.0

gremlin-server-orientdb.yaml file

```
host: localhost
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph : conf/orientdb-empty.properties
}
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    plugins: { org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.jsr223.OrientDBGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin: {classImports: [java.lang.Math], methodImports: [java.lang.Math#*]},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: [../config/demodb.groovy]}}}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.io.OrientIoRegistry] }}             # application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}                                                                       # application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo-stringd
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.io.OrientIoRegistry] }}         # application/json
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000}}
strictTransactionManagement: false
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
authentication: {
  authenticator: com.orientechnologies.tinkerpop.server.auth.OGremlinServerAuthenticator
    }
ssl: {
  enabled: false}
```

orientdb-empty.properties file

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientEmbeddedFactory
```

also, tried with this

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientGraph
```

**stacktrace**

```
admin-12@admin:~/Documents/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.3.1/bin$ ./gremlin-server.sh conf/gremlin-server-orientdb.yaml
[INFO] GremlinServer - 
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----

[INFO] GremlinServer - Configuring Gremlin Server from conf/gremlin-server-orientdb.yaml
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics ConsoleReporter configured with report interval=180000ms
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics CsvReporter configured with report interval=180000ms to fileName=/tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics JmxReporter configured with domain= and agentId=
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
[WARN] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/orientdb-empty.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not find [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientEmbeddedFactory] - Ensure that the jar is in the classpath
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not find [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientEmbeddedFactory] - Ensure that the jar is in the classpath
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.lambda$new$0(DefaultGraphManager.java:57)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:671)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.<init>(DefaultGraphManager.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:80)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:111)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:325)
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.initializeGremlinScriptEngineManager(GremlinExecutor.java:448)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.<init>(GremlinExecutor.java:105)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.<init>(GremlinExecutor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor$Builder.create(GremlinExecutor.java:590)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:128)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:111)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:325
```

**Updated**

```
[WARN] Slf4JLogger - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.orientechnologies.tinkerpop.server.auth.OGremlinServerAuthenticator.authenticate(OGremlinServerAuthenticator.java:34)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.auth.SimpleAuthenticator$PlainTextSaslAuthenticator.getAuthenticatedUser(SimpleAuthenticator.java:143)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.SaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead(SaslAuthenticationHandler.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing a lot of different versions so it's hard to say what will work. First of all, TinkerPop recommends that you try to match the versions of the server with the version of the client. So that means that if you you use 3.3.1 on the server then you should try to use 3.3.1 of a client (in your case gremlin-python). Next, you are using orientdb-gremlin with 3.0.2 which appears to be bound to TinkerPop 3.3.0,

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/3.0.2/driver/pom.xml

which means that for best results you should probably use 3.3.0 on Gremlin Server and gremlin-python. Now, while I mention all this about "matching versions" I will say that it is possible to mix versions, but matching will help limit the things that can go wrong as you're just getting started so I'd encourage you to start there.

As for your error,  I think you installed the wrong dependencies. You should have done:

```
bin/gremlin-server.sh -i com.orientechnologies orientdb-gremlin-server 3.0.2
```

as `orientdb-gremlin-server` will bring in `OrientEmbeddedFactory` as well as the `orientdb-gremlin` dependencies. I also think that your `orientdb-empty.properties` file is missing some configuration options - see what is defaulted and what is not [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/3.0.2/server/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/orientdb/OrientEmbeddedFactory.java).

Comment: downloaded gremlin server 3.3.0 then started the server. it did some process and then stuck. I waited for 10- 15 min but no response I got. I have added the screenshot

Comment: how did you test the connection to gremlin server?

Comment: I solved the problem and now its working fine I installed the dependencies with this command "bin/gremlin-server.sh -i com.orientechnologies orientdb-gremlin 3.0.2"